# What is the meaning of "head-poppingly"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning, sentence-meaning

In a book I'm reading there is a sentence like this

> If you travel to a foreign country, you will make the charming discovery that there are many differences
>   between the local way of life and your own.
>
> Is a cup of coffee over there huge and watery or tiny and head-poppingly strong?

My question is what does it mean by `head-poppingly`?

Please explain for me.

Thanks.

Comment: It's close to being a variant of 'it will blow your head off' (and is used as hypebole, with hints of being literal). 'It will blow you away' is probably better known. More at [Hinative.com](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/361291). It would make many people's eyes water.

Comment: "Head-poppingly" was just invented by this writer.  He wanted to convey: coffee strong enough to make your head pop.

Comment: What they said above. But the "invention" (if such it was) wasn't without precedent, being based on the well-established [***eye-poppingly***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22eye-poppingly%22) (About 2,670 results from Google Books). But I think it's a neat turn of phrase, and may well salt it away for future use.

Comment: Knumber10, that looks like a pure "dictionary" Question that should have been asked of your dictionaries and search engines. What did I miss, please?

Answer (score -1):

"*Is a cup of coffee over there huge and watery or tiny and **head-poppingly** strong?* 
This appears to be a compound word the author made up for emphasis. BTW This is a really awkward sentence and if more context was included, it would've been more helpful.